# What format do both nginx and apache follow to send the request to the app?

Tags: apache, http, nginx

I was just thinking if an app like rails or laravel can receive the request from different server applications like apache or nginx, there must be some sort or request format the servers follow to serve the request to the apps?

What format is this?

Or am I conceptualizing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is the Common Gateway Interface, called "CGI" for short.

https://www.w3.org/CGI/

Comment: Yes exactly. Thank you!